# Why are financial markets modeled by càdlàg processes?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, mathematical-finance, economics

When opening a book or reading an article on mathematical finance, financial markets (e.g. stock prices) are always modeled by càdlàg semimartingales. I was wondering why it is that these processes are assumed to be càdlàg in the first place since there also exists a theory of stochastic integration for optional semimartingales that are not at all assumed to be càdlàg?

Comment: Cadlag is good for prices that move continuously and jump occasionally -- what is your favorite example of a path that is not cadlag but could reasonably be used in a model of stocks?

Comment: Some process that has a double jump. For example, $X_t := 1_{[0,t_0)} + 2 \cdot 1_{(t_0,T]}$ for $0 < t_0 < T < \infty$.

Comment: The initial wording of this question https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27763/why-does-jump-process-has-to-be-cadlag-and-not-the-other-way-around has a striking similarity